# How do I make functions call each other?

Tags: python

I know this is probably really basic and there is an easy answer, but I'm not sure how to make two functions call each other. Function A calls Function B on a condition or two, and function B calls function A on a condition or two. Example:

```
def functionA():
    if something is true:
        functionB()
    if something isn't true:
        something is false
def functionB():
    if something is false:
        functionA()
```

I am pretty bad at python, so if you answer my question please give me an example or two. I know that I am supposed to put the function before it is called, but I'm not sure how to make it work with two functions. Thanks.

Comment: *"I know that I am supposed to put the function before it is called"* - You (generally) don't need to do this in python.  Have you tried running the code in your question?

Comment: You already gave an example. Try it. So long as you don't _call_ either function before both are defined, it will work fine (although your specific example, as written, will soon die with a `RecursionError`, as A and B will keep calling each other forever).

Answer (score 4):

##### What you've already written will "work".

This isn't C; you can *define* a function that calls a function that doesn't yet exist, so as long as you don't *call* such a function until the dependencies exist. As long as neither `functionA` nor `functionB` is called until both are defined, this "works".

The reason I'm quoting "works" is because as written, this will immediately die with a `RecursionError` (the condition for calling each other is the same, so they'd recurse until they hit Python's limit, which you can check by
calling `sys.getrecursionlimit()`). But they would be calling each other as requested, you just need to trigger the first one to be called (e.g. by adding a plain `functionA()` or `functionB()` call after you've defined both of them).

Answer (score -1):

I think one of the most common way to call a function into another function is use callback. It mean you call a function that will call another function you gave it as a parameter.
Here is an example :

```
def sum_numbers(a, b, callback):
res = a + b
callback(res)


def print_result(res):
    print(res)

sum_numbers(1, 8, print_result)
```

Output :

```
9
```

Here the first function calculate the sum and the second just print the result. But for sure you can do a lot of things more interesting with that.

Comment: This is a true thing about how Python uses functions, but seems at best tangentially related to the OP's question, not an answer to their question.